# Set value of callback function nodejs

Tags: javascript, callback, socket.io

```
socket.on('test', function (call, callback){ 
    $('.button_1').on('click', function(){
        callback('button_1 is clicked'); 
    });
    $('.button_2').on('click', function(){
        callback('button_2 is clicked');
    });
});
```

I don't know how to set a value of callback in this situation. 
when i delete the first *callback();* and keep the second one or i delete the second one and keep the first one my code is working fine but when i keep them both the code doesn't work at all

Comment: the callback is a value itself, if you set it, you may erase it, or unref it, depends..

Comment: So what is this? It looks like the clientside part of a socket listener, and if so I think it only has one argument, the data received ?

Comment: @adeneo i don't know what you mean , the code is not working and i don't  know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `callback` is an argument to the function you pass to `on()`, it is the responsibility of the `on()` function to determine the callback.

Based on my reading of the socket.io documentation: It doesn't pass a second argument at all.

So you need to back up.

```
socket.on('test', function (call, callback){ 
                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

Remove that. It won't be used, and will mask any callback in a wider scope.

Then add a callback function elsewhere (i.e. in the wider scope):

```
function callback(string_of_what_is_clicked) {
    alert(string_of_what_is_clicked);
}
socket.on('test', function (call){ 
    $('.button_1').on('click', function(){
        callback('button_1 is clicked'); 
    });
// etc
```

---

> this is a clientside part and it send a callback to server side to tell them which button is clicked . there is no relation between my question and your solution

If you want to send a message from the client to the server when a button is clicked, then you don't do it with `on`. You use `emit`.

```
$('.button_1').on('click', function(){
    socket.emit('button clicked', 'button_1 is clicked'); 
});
```

and then the socket listens for the event:

```
socket.on('button clicked', function (msg) {
    console.log('click: ' + msg);
});
```

Comment: this is a clientside part and it send a callback to server side to tell them which button is clicked . there is no relation between my question and your solution

Comment: @ler — Your question did a very bad job of explaining what you were trying to do. I've updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: i need to send the clicked button name as a callback not as a new socket

Comment: You can't send the name of something as a callback. The name of something a string, a callback must be a function. I have no idea why you think a new socket is involved. You call `emit` on the existing socket.

Comment: i mean i don't want to call emit , anyway i will explain my problem : you said that i cant send a name of something a string that's wrong because when i delete the first **callback('button_1 is clicked');** the code work fine i mean when i click on button 1 it doesn't send anything because i delete the **callback('button_1 is clicked');**  but when i click on the button 2 it send to server **' button 2 is clicked '** so i want to keap both **callback('button_1 is clicked');** and **callback('button_2 is clicked');** and that doesn't work it work just if i delete one and leave one

Comment: "you said that i cant send a name of something a string" — No, I said you couldn't use a string as a callback. You can send a string as data.

Comment: "because when i delete etc etc" — That doesn't make sense. The two bits of are more-or-less identical. They shouldn't behave differently. You need to do some debugging. Test to see what `callback` is inside each of the three functions. Figure out what is changing it.

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean , the problem is not the actual data inside the callback , but when i put both keap both **callback('button_1 is clicked');** and **callback('button_2 is clicked');** , when i delete one my code is work fine

Comment: `callback` is a variable. It shouldn't behave differently. You need to find out why it does. The first thing you should do (aside from looking for error messages in your console) is to test its value (with console.log) in different places and times to see how/if it changes.